# Rails: Select multiple tag objects to associate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

So I'm working on a project where I have a document object (basically an E-Library application) and I have a bunch of Tag objects that I want to be able to associate with it. Currently I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between the two. My question is in the form for a tag, what is the best way to select from a list of available tags to associate with that document? And will I have to do any fancy work in the controller to make this happen?

I'm using rails 3.2

Here is some of the code:

```
# This is the text model
# It will not have an attachment but instead it's children will
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :author, :date, :text_langs_attributes, :notes
  has_many :text_langs, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :item
  validates :author, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :text_langs

    def get_translations
        TextLang.where(:text_id => self.id)
    end

    def get_language(lang)
        TextLang.where(:text_id => self.id, :lang => lang).first
    end
end
```

This is the tag:

```
# This is the Tags class
# It has and belongs to all of the other file classes
# the tags will need to be translated into four langauges
# Tags will also own themselvea
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :creole, :english, :french, :spanish, :cat,
      :english_description, :french_description, :spanish_description,
      :creole_description, :parent_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :texts
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :sounds
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Tag'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Tag', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
  validates :cat, presence: true, inclusion: { in: %w(main sub misc),
    message: "%{value} is not a valid type of tag" }
  validates :english, :spanish, :french, :creole, presence: true

  TYPES = ["main", "sub", "misc"]
end
```

This is the form:

```
= form_for @text do |f|
  - if @text.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@text.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this text from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @text.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name

  .field
    = f.label :date
    = f.date_select :date

  .field
    = f.label :author
    = f.text_field :author

  = f.fields_for :text_langs do |pl|
    .field
      = pl.label :title
      = pl.text_field :title
    .field
      = pl.label :lang
      = pl.text_field :lang
    .field
      = pl.label :description
      = pl.text_field :description, :size => 150
    .field
      = pl.label :plain_text
      = pl.text_area :plain_text
    .field
      = pl.label :published
      = pl.check_box :published
    .field
    = f.label :txt
    = f.file_field :txt


  .field
    = f.label :notes
    = f.text_area :notes, :rows => 10



  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would suggest to try [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) it would make your forms DRY and simple. They have very nice features for associations.

You would end doing something like this:

```
= simple_form_for @text do |f|
  ...
  = f.association :tags,   as: :check_boxes
```

Could be check boxes, radio buttons or maybe a select with multiple values if you need it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that worked but you have to do simple_form_for not form_for. I edited the answer to reflect that.